# compare two table and insert value [postgresql]

Tags: postgresql

I want to compare data between two tables, if `designation` value of **table A**  exists in **table B**, I insert value of `idproduit` correspond this designation of table B in `idproduit` of **table A** like this :

```
table A                         |     table B
---------------------------------   |---------------------------
designation|idproduit|date      |   | designation |idproduit |
--------------------------------|   |------------------------------
des 1      |0        |12/12/2015|   |des1         |5
des 2      |0        |14/06/2015|   |de2          |6
des3       |0        |20/10/2015|   |
```

I want copy value of `idproduit` in table B in table A when `designation` is the same, i do this but it doesn't work
PS: I'm sorry for my english i'm french

```
Insert into calcul(idproduit)  
( Select idproduit 
         from calcul MT 
         where  exists ( select designation 
                            from produit OT 
                            where OT.designation = MT.designation
                          )
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear, but based on your description,I assume, you really need to **UPDATE** column **TableA.idproduct** with values from **TableB.idproduct** where `designation` columns match in both tables.

So your query may be the following:

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET idproduct = b.idproduct
FROM table_b b
WHERE a.designation = b.designation;
```

Sample DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  designation TEXT,
  idproduct INTEGER,
  date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  designation TEXT,
  idproduct INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
  ('des1',0,'2015-12-12'::DATE ),
  ('des2',0,'2015-06-14'::DATE ),
  ('des3',0,'2015-10-20'::DATE );

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES
  ('des1',5),
  ('des2',6);
```

Comment: you undrstand my problem, i have problem with your request, b it's not rognizeded

Comment: I get this error
ERRor:  column b.idproduct doen't exist
LINE 2: SET idproduct = b.idproduct
problem with b dont recognized

Comment: adjust your column names `idproduit ` I have a little bit different @khadi8

Comment: oups, it's true sorry :D